# Iterate through a dictionary and save webpages (values) to files with keys as names

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm new to python and for loops.
I have a dictionary like

```
{'Austria': 'https://example.com/austria', 'Australia': 'https://example.com/australia',... }
```

I want to download each webpage's contents to a respective file: Austria.html, Australia.html,...

What I tried so far is not working, but I hope to show what I'm trying to do.

```
for country, link in country_links.items():
    for i in country_links.values():
        links = requests.get(i)
        contents = links.content     
    with open(country + ".html", "w") as file: 
        file.write(contents)
```

Comment: you are using `country_links.items()` they why do you need this `for i in country_links.values()`

Comment: @deadshot true, that's unnecessary and seems to create an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost what required to achieve what you want, few minor fixes:

1. At line 9, changed `state` to `country`, as the loop is on `country`
2. Converted response to a string so we can save it to a textual file
3. Removed a redundant loop

```
import requests

country_links = {'Austria': 'https://example.com/austria', 'Australia': 'https://example.com/australia',}

# Going on each country and it's link
for country, link in country_links.items():
    # Getting link
    req = requests.get(link)
    # Convert content to string
    contents = str(req.content, 'utf-8')
    # Write country content to a file
    with open(country + ".html", "w") as file:
        file.write(contents)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the redundant loop was creating an issue: it was saving the files but the content was the same: the last country. Now it works perfectly. Thank you.